# Duvida simples em JS - imput para textarea

Tags: javascript, html, maps-javascript-api

Estou com uma duvida para saber se consigo continuar um projeto que peguei pronto mas esta com alguns problemas.

o problema eh que o projeto todo esta voltando para os valores que sao inseridos no HTML pelo codigo `<imput>` e o imput na questao de Texto eh muito limitado e gostaria de trocar pelo opcao de `<textarea>` que funciona muito melhor e tem varias possibilidades.

Como sou leigo no JS ainda gostaria de saber se eh possivel trocar para o `<textarea>` visto que todo o processo de JS esta referenciando ao `<imput>` pelo `querySelector('tr:last-child imput')` (esse eh apenas um exemplo), seria simples como trocar para textarea? Eh possivel trocar pelo textarea dentro do projeto e ele continuar funcionando igual visto que os 2 usam apenas o texto inserido ?

Agradeco desde ja! vlw!

Comment: sim é possível usar um textarea no lugar de um input

Answer (score 1):

O método `querySelector()` retorna o primeiro elemento que corresponde a um seletor(es) CSS especificado(s) no documento. Com isso você poderia alterar o `input` pelo `textarea` sem maiores problemas.

Se o seletor corresponder a um ID no documento que é usado várias vezes (observe que um "id" deve ser único em uma página e não deve ser usado mais de uma vez), ele retorna o primeiro elemento correspondente.

Exemplo:

Obtenha o primeiro elemento `<textarea>` no documento:

```
document.querySelector("textarea");
```